# Using JsonContent.Create for properties that are not valid C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I like `JsonContent.Create`.  It allows me to create a POST body like this:

```
using var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, myUrl);
message.Content = JsonContent.Create(new { displayName = myDisplayName});
```

This is great for properties like `displayName`.  But now I am trying to call an MS Graph service, and it requires me to put this in as a property:

```
@odata.id = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/46026638-208d-4c03-bb85-d42f0c472484"
```

`@odata.id` is not a valid C# identifier.

Is there a way to use `JsonContent.Create` with odd properties like `@odata.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using dictionaries:

```cs
var jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "@odata.id", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/46026638-208d-4c03-bb85-d42f0c472484" }
});
```

Or create custom class marking field with proper attribute:

```cs
public class MyClass1
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@odata.id")]
    public string OdataId { get; set; }
}

var jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(new MyClass1
{
    OdataId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/46026638-208d-4c03-bb85-d42f0c472484"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary with `string` as key type. Think of json objects being instances of `Dictionary<string, object>` (or some other appropriate type for the values that's more specialized than *object*).

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict["@odata.id"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/46026638-208d-4c03-bb85-d42f0c472484";


message.Content = JsonContent.Create(dict);
```